# How to show dynamic column using Pivot table

Tags: sql-server

I have a query

```
declare @Leavetype varchar (Max)    
select @Leavetype =(select LeaveName from LeaveType)     

SELECT *
 FROM 
 ( SELECT e.EmpID,
 e.EmpName , 
 s.LeaveName, 
 case when l.Approval = 'Approved'
 then l.TotalDays 
 else
 0
 end  AS Total
  from  EmpInfo e
  full JOIN  ViewLeave l   ON e.EmpID = l.EmpID
  LEFT  JOIN LeaveType  s  ON s.LeaveID = l.LeaveID    

 Where
      l.year = '2013'              

 GROUP BY s.LeaveName,e.EmpID, e.EmpName ,l.Approval,l.TotalDays
 )ps
 pivot
 (
 sum(Total)
 for LeaveName In ([@LeaveType])

 )as pvt
```

I want to take dynamic value from leave type table `Leavetype`

`LeaveType` table is as follows

```
ID   Leave type
1    SickLeave
2    Casual Leave
```

`LeaveType` table value can vary and I have to show data like

```
EmpId    EmpName    SickLeave     Casual Leave 

101      ramesh       1               0
```

No of columns depends on the no of rows in the `Leavetype` table

If anyone has an idea, please help me

This current query shows error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to the idea but you must use dynamic sql to dynamically pivot a table. The error you have is because of `select @Leavetype =(select LeaveName from LeaveType)` i.e. only one value can be returned by the subquery in order to assign is to the variable.

What you need to do is roughly like the following where a comma separated string of values (columns) is used to build the pivot query.

```
-- get a comma delimited string of the columns
DECLARE @leaveType NVARCHAR(1000)
SELECT @leaveType = STUFF(
                      (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT '],[' + LeaveName
                       FROM LeaveType AS t
                       FOR XML PATH('') 
                      ), 1, 2, ''
                    ) + ']'

-- create the sql script to be executed
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(3000) = N'
    WITH data AS
    (
        SELECT 
            e.EmpID,
            e.EmpName , 
            s.LeaveName, 
            Total = CASE l.Approval 
                        WHEN ''Approved'' THEN l.TotalDays 
                        ELSE 0 
                    END
        FROM EmpInfo e
        FULL JOIN ViewLeave l ON e.EmpID = l.EmpID
        LEFT JOIN LeaveType s ON s.LeaveID = l.LeaveID
        GROUP BY s.LeaveName, e.EmpID, e.EmpName, l.Approval, l.TotalDays
    )

    SELECT *
    FROM data
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(Total)
        FOR LeaveName IN (' + @leaveType + ')
    ) piv
' 

PRINT @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

[Here](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2007/09/14/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005/) is a blog post discussing `PIVOT` in more detail

Comment: this code is running fine in sql server but when i use this query (after making stored procedure) in coding its showing error **onversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '**

Comment: have you made any changes or added anything in you're proc? if so you're best off asking another question with the code you are using in the stored procedure. you could also try explicitly casting `LeaveName` to `NVARCHAR(n)`.